# How to calculate multiple percentage after percentage based on a value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem to solve on how to calculate percentage after percentage if exists in SQL.

There are many type of percentage format I want my calculation to be dynamic to each of the format but I don't know how to do it. The max discount in single calculation are 3 discount for example like **50%/10%/5%** which means

```
Price - 50% = 1st total

1st Total - 10% = 2nd total

2nd total - 5% = final total
```

I only manage to deal with 2 discount types of the format. For example **50%** and **50%/10%**

But when it comes to single digit then it will error. For example like **50%/5%**

Example flows that I want is:

**`Price : 13.24`**

**`Discount format type`**

1. if discount is **0.32** then `(13.24 - (13.24 * 0.32/100)) = costafterdiscount`
2. if discount is **32** then `(13.24 - (13.24 * 32/100)) = costafterdiscount`
3. if discount is **32%** then `(13.24 - (13.24 * 32/100)) = costafterdiscount`
4. if discount is **3.2** then `(13.24 - (13.24 * 3.2/100)) = costafterdiscount`
5. if discount is **32%/5%** then (`(13.24  - (13.24  * 32/100)) - ((13.24  - (13.24  * 32/100)) * 5/100)) = costafterdiscount`
6. if discount is **32%/5.2%** then `((13.24 - (13.24 * 32/100)) - ((13.24 - (13.24 * 32/100)) * 5.2/100))= costafterdiscount`
7. if discount is **32%+5%6%** then `((13.24 - (13.24 * 32/100)) - ((13.24 - (13.24 * 32/100)) * 5/100)) - (((13.24 - (13.24 * 32/100)) - ((13.24 - (13.24 * 32/100)) * 5/100)) * 6/100) = costafterdiscount`
8. if discount is **32%/5.2+6%** then `((13.24 - (13.24 * 32/100)) - ((13.24 - (13.24 * 32/100)) * 5.2/100)) - (((13.24 - (13.24 * 32/100)) - ((13.24 - (13.24 * 32/100)) * 5.2/100)) * 6/100) = costafterdiscount`
9. if discount is **32+5.2+6** then `((13.24 - (13.24 * 32/100)) - ((13.24 - (13.24 * 32/100)) * 5.2/100)) - (((13.24 - (13.24 * 32/100)) - ((13.24 - (13.24 * 32/100)) * 5.2/100)) * 6/100) = costafterdiscount`
10. if discount is **100%** then `(13.24 - (13.24 * 100/100)) = costafterdiscount`
11. if discount is **100** then `(13.24 - (13.24 * 100/100)) = costafterdiscount`
12. if discount is **NETT** then `13.24 = costafterdiscount`

I have provided a sample of my database below. Please give me advice on how to do this.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/80dc66/4)

Here's how my code looks like

```
select
    StockCode,
    Price,
    discount,
    (Price - (Price * discount1 / 100)) - ((Price - (Price * discount1 / 100)) * discount2 / 100 ) as costafterdiscount
from (
    select
        StockCode,
        Price,
        discount,
        case when discount1 = 0 then null else discount1 end as discount1,
        case when discount2 = 0 or discount2 = discount1 then null else discount2 end as discount2      
    from (
        select 
            StockCode,
            discount,
            CAST(Price AS float) as Price,
            CAST(replace(left(discount, 2), '%', '') AS float) as discount1,
            CAST(replace(right(discount, 2), '%', '') AS float) as discount2
        from Stocks
    ) st
) stt
```

Comment: the `discount` string is totally unstructured. It will be very difficult to handle such. You need to parse it to determine the discount format type and also the discount string. Is it possible to make it structured ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After taking a second look at your discount type, there are only 3 different type.

- Type 1 : decimal value with or without `%`
- Type 2 : string "NETT"
- Type 3 : multiple decimal value separated by `/` or `+`

Firstly is to clean up your `Discount` using `translate()` to replace `/`, `+` with ',' as a separator. `%` is replace with `space`

After that use `charindex()` to extract individual decimal value. That is what the `CROSS APPLY()` is doing

To calculate the discounted price, it uses a different calculation way

```
  Discounted Price = Price - (100 - discount_percentage) / 100
```

The effect is the same. Just makes it easier as you don't need to calculate the intermediate price after each discount

---

```
select disc_price = s.Price
                  * (100.00 - case when s1.t = 'NETT' then 100.00 else isnull(s1.t, 0.00) end) / 100.0
                  * (100.00 - case when s2.t = 'NETT' then 100.00 else isnull(s2.t, 0.00) end) / 100.0
                  * (100.00 - case when s3.t = 'NETT' then 100.00 else isnull(s3.t, 0.00) end) / 100.0
from   Stocks s
       cross apply
       (
           select   disc = replace(translate(s.Discount, '%/+', ' ,,'), ',,', ',')
       ) d
       cross apply
       (
           select   t    = nullif(left(d.disc, p - 1), ''),
                    disc = stuff(d.disc, 1, p, '')
           from    (select p = charindex(',', d.disc + ',')) p
       ) s1
       cross apply
       (
           select   t    = nullif(left(s1.disc, p - 1), ''),
                    disc = stuff(s1.disc, 1, p, '')
           from    (select p = charindex(',', s1.disc + ',')) p
       ) s2
       cross apply
       (
           select   t    = nullif(left(s2.disc, p - 1), ''),
                    disc = stuff(s2.disc, 1, p, '')
           from    (select p = charindex(',', s2.disc + ',')) p
       ) s3
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/80dc66/19)